# Can't get my Hash::combine right in CakePHP

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, hash

I have an array that I'm trying to remodel with Hash::combine.

This is my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [T1] => Array
                (
                    [second] => APPLES
                    [Color] => GREEN
                    [Color_en] => #99cc66
                    [nombre] => 56
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [T1] => Array
                (
                    [second] => APPLES
                    [Color] => BLUE
                    [Color_en] => #0099ff
                    [nombre] => 678
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [T1] => Array
                (
                    [second] => BANANAS
                    [Color] => GREEN
                    [Color_en] => #99cc66
                    [nombre] => 366
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [T1] => Array
                (
                    [second] => BANANAS
                    [Color] => BLUE
                    [Color_en] => #0099ff
                    [nombre] => 2000
                )

        )
)
```

And what I want to achieve is the array below :

```
Array
    (
        [0] =>  Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [y] => 56
                    [color] => #99cc66
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [y] => 678
                    [color] => #0099ff
                )

            )
        )
        [1] =>  Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [y] => 366
                    [color] => #99cc66
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [y] => 2000
                    [color] => #0099ff
                )

            )
        )
```

So first array is "APPLES" and second is "BANANAS", "y" is "nombre and "Color_en" becomes "color".

I've tried so many different ways with Hash::combine but I'm out of ideas how tho do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is outside the scope of `Hash::combine()`. You can't use it to rename array indices.

The closest thing you could probably do is combine the array values by `{n}.T1.second` to group the fruits together like this:-

```
Hash::combine($array, '{n}.T1.nombre', '{n}.T1', '{n}.T1.second');
```

For what you are trying to achieve you will need to rebuild the array yourself using a `foreach` loop. Something like this:-

```
$data = [];
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $data[$value['T1']['second']][] = [
        'y' => $value['T1']['nombre'],
        'color' => $value['T1']['Color_en']
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

What if I renamed nombre as "y", Color_en as "color" (and obviously Color as something else like "x"). It all comes from a database so it's easy for me to do.

Would it then be possible to use Hash::combine()

Comment: Renaming columns in a database in order to get `Hash::combine()` working sounds like a bit of a backwards approach to getting something working and not ideal. I still don't think it will help you achieve quite what you want. `Hash::combine()` is very useful for many cases, but I don't think it is the right solution for what you are trying to achieve without over complicating things. At the end of the day the `Hash` utility will be iterating over your array so if you can easily achieve the desired result with a custom `foreach` I'd do that.

Comment: I'll go for your solution. Thank you very much for your help !